# Can't get arcpy.management.Rename to run

Tags: python, arcgis, arcpy

I'm trying to write a script where users can build the feature class name that aligns with our standards by selecting values. everything else in this script seems to work fine (you can print layername and it works correctly). I'm not getting an error and I've tried forcing it to give me an error by changing the variables that are used in the function, but it still finishes the script in half a second and doesn't change anything.

```py
import arcpy

#Get Parameters
FC = arcpy.GetParameter(0) #Required
unit = arcpy.GetParameter(1)
sunit = arcpy.GetParameter(2)
sens = arcpy.GetParameter(3)
cat = arcpy.GetParameter(4) #Required
name = arcpy.GetParameter(5) #Required
location = arcpy.GetParameter(6)
daterange = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(7)
date = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(8)
startdate = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(9)
enddate = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(10)
resolution = arcpy.GetParameter(11)
source = arcpy.GetParameter(12)
dt = arcpy.GetParameter(13) #Required

#Construct layer name
##Unit
if unit != "":
    unit = unit + "_"
##Subunit
if sunit != "":
    sunit = unit + "_"
##SENSITIVITY
if sens == "Yes":
    sens = "SENSITIVE_"
elif sens == "Yes, at the feature level":
    sens = "SENSITIVEFL_"
##Category
cat = cat.split(" -")[0] + "_"
##Layer Name
##Modifiers
###Location
location = location.replace(" ", "")
###Date
if daterange == "true":
    date = "startdate" + "-" + "enddate"
###Source
source = source.replace(" ", "")
##Data Type
if dt == "Point":
    dt = "_pt"
elif dt == "Line":
    dt = "_ln"
elif dt == "Polygon":
    dt = "_py"
elif dt == "Raster":
    dt = "_ra"
elif dt == "Non-feature Attribute Table":
    dt = "_tbl"
#Assign layer name
##Form new name
layername = unit + sunit + sens + cat + location + date + source + dt
layername = layername.replace("__", "_").replace(" ", "")
##Assign name to feature class
arcpy.management.Rename = (FC, layername, "FeatureClass")
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your script... I am just going to point out *a few of them*. You should clean-up your script and make it more error-prone.

**Main Issue**

1. `arcpy.management.Rename` is a function and not a property. You cannot assign a tuple. Remove the equals sign (`=`):

```py
# DOES NOT WORK: arcpy.management.Rename = (FC, layername, "FeatureClass")
arcpy.management.Rename(FC, layername, "FeatureClass")
```

**Secondary Main Issue** (if a feature class within a geodatabase is used)

2. `-` is not allowed in a name of a feature class in a geodatabase. Replace the character with another one. For example:

```
date = "startdate" + "_" + "enddate"
```

**A few other Issues**

3. Also, in this line, you are using `"startdate"` and `"enddate"`. I assume that is not intentional. Remove the quotation marks:

```
date = startdate + "_" + enddate
```

4. It is assumed that `startdate` and `enddate` are strings, if they are `datetime` or `date` objects, then you may want to format them using [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime).
5. `date` is read from a parameter, but then set if `daterange` is `"true"`. `date` is not formatted when `daterange` is another value.
6. Is `daterange` really a string and not a boolean?
7. If `startdate` and `enddate` are strings, what if they contain special characters?
8. What happens if `cat` does not have a  `-` within the string?
9. What if `dt` is neither one of the options? I assume you have a dropdown and this is not the case.

---

Here is a working example with some test parameters in order to run it from the terminal. Please note that I only corrected your main issues (issues 1 and 2) in the example below:

```py
import arcpy

FC = r"D:\test\Washrooms.gdb\Washrooms"
unit = ""
sunit = ""
sens = "Yes, at the feature level"
cat = "Test Category - Some Description"
name = "Washroom Features"
location = ""
daterange = "true"  # or boolean?
date = ""  # why? date is overwritten later...
startdate = "08/05/1989"  # or datetime?
enddate = "30/08/2003"  # or datetime?
resolution = ""
source = ""
dt = "Point"  # must be a dropdown, right?
```

```
if unit != "":
    unit = unit + "_"

if sunit != "":
    sunit = unit + "_"

if sens == "Yes":
    sens = "SENSITIVE_"
elif sens == "Yes, at the feature level":
    sens = "SENSITIVEFL_"

cat = cat.split(" -")[0] + "_"

location = location.replace(" ", "")

if daterange == "true":
    date = "startdate" + "_" + "enddate"

source = source.replace(" ", "")

if dt == "Point":
    dt = "_pt"
elif dt == "Line":
    dt = "_ln"
elif dt == "Polygon":
    dt = "_py"
elif dt == "Raster":
    dt = "_ra"
elif dt == "Non-feature Attribute Table":
    dt = "_tbl"
```

```
layername = unit + sunit + sens + cat + location + date + source + dt
layername = layername.replace("__", "_").replace(" ", "")

arcpy.management.Rename(FC, layername, "FeatureClass")
```